# MacBook can not boot OS X Yosemite as it hangs

Tags: macos, mac, boot, macbook

I have unsolved problem with my macbook.
Once when my mac was alive, I've set rights to all data on mac HD for user 'system' to read-only. Also I do it for the groups 'wheel' and 'stuff'. Only one user account with name 'mac01' has all rights to data on my mac HD. After this (why I made it, I can not explain, it's my fault) my mac goes down and can not boot the system.
As decision, I run system in Single-User Mode and type:

```
fsck -f
mount -uw /
chmod -R ugo+rwx /
```

But it still not help me.
System still can not boot, and stops above 55% loading apple logo screen.

In Verbose Mode the last string is:

> en0: channel changed to 1

then boot stops for unknown time.

Please, help me if you can. I would be appreciate for your help! Thanks.

[image: OS X boot - en0: channel changed to 1]

The last lines in the verbose mode are:

```
IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlOperatingMode Setting the AWDL operation mode from SUSPENDED to AUTO
IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlAutoMode Resuming AWDL
en0: BSSID changed to 28:28:xx:xx:xx:xx
en0: channel changed to 1
```

and it hangs/freezes.

I did run in recovery mode, run Disk Utility, fsck and verified/fixed the permissions, but it didn't help.

Comment: Run system in [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) and check on what part it's freezes and type the error you've got.

Comment: last string in Verbose Mobe is: "en0: channel changed to 1"

Comment: and then boot stops for unknown time

Comment: Can you try to run in [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)? Then run Disk Utility and 1. Fix the errors on your HDD (it could also fix common boot problems), 2. Verify and fix the permissions. Because `chmod -R ugo+rwx /` wasn't a good idea to do.

Comment: I try but this can not help, system still can not boot OS

Comment: You can still run recovery, because recovery should be there on another hidden partition so usually you can run it without any problems, unless you broke your OS X completely.

Comment: recovery didn't help me(( I'am so sad. Please, is there any another way to repair my breakdown?

Comment: Do you mean recovery partition works, you ran Disk Utility repair and permission fixes, but still doesn't work? Or recovery boot doesn't work  at all?

Comment: I ran Disk Utility but still doesn't work

Comment: I make permission fixes, but it did not help

Comment: You may copy your data and re-install OS X. Alternatively try [DiskWarrior Repair](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) tool (and its recovery DVD), but it's not free, so it's just suggestion. Another thing is to log-in into single mode and type `exit` to boot into GUI mode (maybe it would help to find the reason of freeze). Check also in single mode the logs, maybe you'll find something useful, e.g. `sudo tail /var/log/*.log`.

Comment: thank you for your help! I will try and tell about results

Comment: but anyway i did not understand OS X structure. I mean that mac os admin user can set new permissions under the shell and the root user can not resolve his mistakes under single-user mode. It's amazing

Comment: You can solve your problem under single mode, but you need to figure it out first what's the problem. Without any specific error, it's difficult to track it down. If you've TimeMachine, maybe it's worth to recover system data. If you've access to different Mac, you can `scp` the system files with proper permissions. All system files should be in general owned by `root`, not by `system`.

Comment: This is the log in Single-Mode after I write 'exit': [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CFeMOcuUUAAlpep.jpg:large)

Comment: This is my root directory [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CFeO_2zXIAALGJx.jpg:large)

Comment: I'm out of ideas for today, I've updated your question for new info if that's ok. Maybe somebody else would have some other ideas. Check `/cores` if you've any fresh core dumps which could indicate what crashed.  Try also restart your [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) & PRAM.

Answer (score 8):

> I've set rights to all data on mac HD for user 'system' to read-only. Also I do it for the groups 'wheel' and 'stuff'. Only one user account with name 'mac01' has all rights to data on my mac HD.

If you messed up with OS X permissions, normally you should run Disk Utility in [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and run [Repair Disk Permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560) and *Repair Disk* or *First Aid* (in *El Capitan*) to correct errors on HDD and eventually fix the boot loader. In most cases it should work.

To fix it manually, you should run in [single mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) and try to fix it the permissions on [system folders](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18774) manually, for example:

```
chown -R root /System /Library
chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /System /Library
```

and then type [`exit`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125624/22781) to continue the startup process and note any meaningful errors.

If this won't help, here are the things to consider:

- disconnect any external devices that are connected (if any),
- try to run your Mac in [Safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262),
- check for fresh core dumps `/cores` (this could indicate some problem with specific component),
- check for anything suspicious in logs (`tail /var/log/*.log`, especially `system.log`),
- reset your [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) & [PRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761),
- [unload 3rd party kernel extensions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/54824/22781) (in single mode, probably you need to relocate them from `/System/Library/Extensions`, but if you didn't install any (like `vboxdrv`), better leave it, as it may get worse),
- in single mode, verify your NVRAM variables `sudo nvram -p` and consider to run your kernel in different mode, for example:

  - debugging mode: [`sudo nvram boot-args="debug=0x144"`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/155193/22781)

  For more options, check: [Boot argument options in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/news/boot-argument-options-in-os-x/).
  When it work, don't forget to disable it.
- consider using 3rd party recovery tools (e.g. recovery DVD from [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/)),
- consider reinstalling your OS X.